# UI Integration with Unity 3D and Fusetools

Tags: web-services, rest, user-interface, unity-game-engine, hybrid-mobile-app

I need to integrate [FuseTools](https://www.fusetools.com) animation samples to unity 3d animations. Can you please tell me is it possible and what suitable method should i approach ?
 Thanks

Comment: Negating the -1 when no reason given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an interest in [FuseTools](http://www.fusetools.com) too. I think one approach would be using the [Foreign Code](https://www.fusetools.com/docs/native-interop/foreign-code) feature to wrap Unity 3D. This wouldn't be an easy task. There are some discussions regarding graphics in the Fuse forums, I would suggest to have a look before venturing further.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done.

**Unity** and **FUSE(tools)** both compiles projects to APPS ready to publish, neither one of them can generate code that can be used or embeded outside their platform.

**Unity** uses **IL2CPP** to create C++ code. **Fuse(tools)** uses **UNO** for the same purpose.

Maybe if you can unwrap both compiled projects there is a way to mix things, but at the end, it would be easier to code directly on **Java** or **Objective-C** | **Swift**.